# Bind dataframes in a list two by two (or by name) - R

Tags: r, bind

Lets say I have this list of dataframes:

```
  DF1_A<- data.frame (first_column  = c("A", "B","C"),
                    second_column = c(5, 5, 5),
                    third_column = c(1, 1, 1)
)

DF1_B <- data.frame (first_column  = c("A", "B","E"),
                     second_column = c(1, 1, 5),
                     third_column = c(1, 1, 1)
)

DF2_A <- data.frame (first_column  = c("E", "F","G"),
                     second_column = c(1, 1, 5),
                     third_column = c(1, 1, 1)
)

DF2_B <- data.frame (first_column  = c("K", "L","B"),
                     second_column = c(1, 1, 5),
                     third_column = c(1, 1, 1)
)

mylist <- list(DF1_A, DF1_B, DF2_A, DF2_B)
names(mylist) = c("DF1_A", "DF1_B", "DF2_A", "DF2_B")


mylist =  lapply(mylist, function(x){
  x[, "first_column"] <- as.character(x[, "first_column"])
  x
})
```

I want to bind them by their name (All DF1, All DF2 etc), or, objectively, two by two in this ordered named list. Keeping the "named list structure" of the list is important to keep track (for example, DF1_A and DF1_B = DF1 or something similiar in the names(mylist))

There are some rows that have duplicated values, and I want to keep them (which will introduce some duplicated characters such as first_column, value A)

I have tried finding any clues here on stack overflow, but most people want to bind dataframes irrespective of their names or orders.

Final result would look something like this:

```
mylist
DF1
DF2

DF1
first_column    second_column   third_column
A               1               1
A               5               1
B               1               1
B               5               1
C               5               1
E               5               1
```

Comment: In your question, you say "merge", "bind" and "+" -- all of which sound like different operations. Can you please show the expected result for `DF1`?

Comment: And when you say "Keeping the name", do you mean that you need to be able to identify which data frame every observation in the result came from? Or just that you need to know which two data frames are part of a given resulting data frame?

Comment: I edited the question to make more sense

Comment: Also, your R version might be nice to know - or at least the class of the columns. In R version 4.0, R switched from the old default that `first_column` would be `factor` class to the new default that it would be `character` class.

Comment: Do you have more suffixes or `"A"` and  `"B"` are the only ones?

Comment: A and B are the only ones, but if you think a more generic approach is better, then no problem! I haven't seem any question similar to this in stack, so a general approach might be better

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

```
lapply(
  split(mylist, gsub("_.*", "", names(mylist))),
  function(v) `row.names<-`((out <- do.call(rbind, v))[do.call(order, out), ], NULL)
)
```

which gives

```
$DF1
  first_column second_column third_column
1            A             1            1
2            A             5            1
3            B             1            1
4            B             5            1
5            C             5            1
6            E             5            1

$DF2
  first_column second_column third_column
1            B             5            1
2            E             1            1
3            F             1            1
4            G             5            1
5            K             1            1
6            L             1            1
```

Comment: I think the first one lapply(
  split(mylist, gsub("_.*", "", names(mylist))),
  function(v) `row.names<-`((out <- do.call(rbind, v))[do.call(order, out), ], NULL)
) is better, just because it gives you the rownames naming where this variable came from!

Comment: @GabrielG. Thanks. I think the title of your question should be `stack` or `row bind`, rather than `merge`. Better to make a clearer title for other readers.

Comment: Can I select the number of collumns to rbind, in case the df's have a different number of them? for example [,1:3]?

Comment: @GabrielG. Yes, you can, but you should ensure that the columns you selected having the same column names (since `rbind` requires this). It is better to select columns by their names, instead of indices.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution with `Map`, but it only works for two suffixes. If you want to `merge`, use the first `Map` instruction; if you want to keep duplicates, use the 2nd, `rbind` solution.

```
sp <- split(mylist, sub("^DF.*_", "", names(mylist)))
res1 <- Map(function(x, y)merge(x, y, all = TRUE), sp[["A"]], sp[["B"]])
res2 <- Map(function(x, y)rbind(x, y), sp[["A"]], sp[["B"]])

names(res1) <- sub("_.*$", "", names(res1))
names(res2) <- sub("_.*$", "", names(res2))
```

Answer (score 0):

One of many obligatory `tidyverse` solutions can be this.

```r
library(purrr)
library(stringr)

# find the unique DF names
unique_df <- set_names(unique(str_split_fixed(names(mylist), "_", 2)[,1]))

# loop over each unique name, extracting the elements and binding into columns
purrr::map(unique_df, ~ keep(mylist, str_starts(names(mylist), .x))) %>% 
  map(bind_rows)
```

Also for things like this, `bind_rows()` from `dplyr` has a `.id` argument which will add a column with the list element name, and stack the rows. That can also be a helpful way. You can bind, manipulate the name how you'd like, and then `split()`.